# Некорректная работа запроса SQL?

Tags: sql

Прохожу учебный курс по развитию навыков составления запросов в базу данных. Столкнулся с запросом (смотри ниже), который выдает ошибку: 
отсутствует колонка avg_budget. Ошибку можно устранить, если вместо avg_budget в строке с условием:`HAVING avg_budget >= 60000000` заменить `avg_budget` на агрегатную функцию - `AVG(budget)`. В принципе понятно, что на момент составления запроса колонки avg_budget нету.

Меня смущает тот факт, что при сортировке результата запроса по названию avg_gross ошибки не возникает, хотя по логике должно, ведь колонки avg_gross тоже не существует.
Запрос с ошибкой:

```
SELECT release_year, AVG(budget) AS avg_budget, AVG(gross) AS avg_gross
FROM films
WHERE release_year > 1990
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING avg_budget >= 60000000
ORDER BY avg_gross DESC;
```

Тот же запрос без ошибки:

```
SELECT release_year, AVG(budget) AS avg_budget, AVG(gross) AS avg_gross
FROM films
WHERE release_year > 1990
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING AVG(budget)>= 60000000
ORDER BY avg_gross DESC;
```

Comment: у вас есть 6 инструкций `select, from, where, group by, having, order` попробуйте выяснить в каком порядке они работают, и ответ на вопрос станет понятен

Comment: Особенно, на разницу между `HAVING` и `WHERE`

Comment: *выдает ошибку: отсутствует колонка avg_budget* Зависит от СУБД, которую Вы постеснялись указать. Некоторые дают ошибку, другие нормально воспринимают такой запрос.

Comment: @teran Добавь в это список ещё оконные функции - и всё снова станет непонятным...